# ValueError: Graph disconnected - How to split a keras model into submodels

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow

The following snippet should replicate the error if you have `keras` and `tensorflow` installed:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import Concatenate, Dense, LSTM, Flatten, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Bidirectional, GaussianNoise, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM as LSTM

# Dimensions
input_shape = (105, 29)
dec_input_shape = (104, 29)

output_len = 104
output_dims = 29

lstm_dim = 256
bottleneck_dim = 128
h_activation = "relu"

bn_momentum=0.9

# Architecture
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = encoder_inputs

encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_dim//2,
               return_sequences=True,
               return_state=True,
               name="Encoder_LSTM"))

encoder2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_dim//2,
               return_state=True, 
               name="Encoder_LSTM2"))

x ,state_h, state_c, state_h_reverse, state_c_reverse = encoder(x)
x = BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum)(x)
encoder_outputs, state_h2, state_c2 , state_h2_reverse, state_c2_reverse = encoder2(x)

states = Concatenate(axis=-1)([state_h, state_c, state_h2, state_c2,
                              state_h_reverse, state_c_reverse, state_h2_reverse, state_c2_reverse])

states = BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum)(states)

neck_relu = Dense(bottleneck_dim, activation=h_activation, name='bottleneck_relu')
neck_outputs = neck_relu(states)
neck_outputs = BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum, name="BN_bottleneck")(neck_outputs)

decode_h = Dense(lstm_dim, activation="relu")
decode_c = Dense(lstm_dim, activation="relu")
decode_h2 = Dense(lstm_dim, activation="relu")
decode_c2 = Dense(lstm_dim, activation="relu")

state_h_decoded =  decode_h(neck_outputs)
state_c_decoded =  decode_c(neck_outputs)
state_h_decoded2 =  decode_h2(neck_outputs)
state_c_decoded2 =  decode_c2(neck_outputs)

state_h_decoded_BN =  BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum)
state_c_decoded_BN =  BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum)
state_h_decoded2_BN =  BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum)
state_c_decoded2_BN =  BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum)

state_h_decoded =  state_h_decoded_BN(state_h_decoded)
state_c_decoded =  state_c_decoded_BN(state_c_decoded)
state_h_decoded2 =  state_h_decoded2_BN(state_h_decoded2)
state_c_decoded2 =  state_c_decoded2_BN(state_c_decoded2)

encoder_states = [state_h_decoded, state_c_decoded]
encoder_states2 = [state_h_decoded2, state_c_decoded2]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=dec_input_shape)

decoder_lstm = LSTM(lstm_dim,
                    return_sequences=True,
                    name='LSTM1_decoder'
                   )
decoder_lstm2 = LSTM(lstm_dim,
                    return_sequences=True,
                    name='LSTM2_decoder'
                   )


xo = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
xo = BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum, name="BN_decoder")(xo)
decoder_outputs = decoder_lstm2(xo, initial_state=encoder_states2)

outputs = Dense(output_dims, activation='softmax', name="Dense_decoder")(decoder_outputs)

# Define model
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs)
```

The summary of the model is:
[image]

I want to create a sub-model out of the full model, that will have as input the output of layer `input_11` and as output the output of the last layer, i.e. `Dense_decoder`. Therefore, I define the new model as:

```
model_new = Model(model.get_layer("input_11").output, model.get_layer("Dense_decoder").output)
```

which gives me the following error, that the **graph has been disconnected**:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_10:0", shape=(?, 105, 29), dtype=float32) at layer "input_10". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Any idea why this happens? Or generally how to circumvent the issue and define `model_new` as a sub-model of the existing full model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I could not get your example to run. Here is a code sample where a new model built from parts of an existing model:

```py
# Explicitly define new model input and output by slicing out old model layers
model_new = Model(input=model_old.layers[0].input, 
                  output=model_old.layers[12].output)

# Compile model to inspect
model_new.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

# Visually inspect new model to confirm it has the correct architecture
model_new.summary()
```

Comment: I have a pre-trained VGG16 with Imagenet. I want to use the encoder from this network as a feature extractor. Your answer, will let me extract the encoder? Thanks. I have asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465734/how-to-get-the-encoder-from-a-trained-vgg16-network

Comment: what if you wan't to slice it from the middle?
I get `Graph disconnected` error by using the slice `model.layers[2], model.layers[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to create the submodel as you define it because the `LSTM1_decoder` and `LSTM2_decoder` layers both depend on previous model layers (and hence ultimately on the initial input layer) through their initial states. From your code:

```
xo = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_outputs = decoder_lstm2(xo, initial_state=encoder_states2)
```

The definition of `model_new`:

```
model_new = Model(model.get_layer("input_11").output, model.get_layer("Dense_decoder").output)
```

can also be written as

```
model_new = Model(decoder_inputs, outputs)
```

which when compared to your original model definition:

```
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs)
```

makes the problem clear - you also need the encoder_inputs, at which point the two models are identical.